# Is it possible to compile Ruby to byte code as with Python?

Tags: ruby

In Python, if I want to give out an application without sources I can compile it into bytecode .pyc, is there a way to do something like it in Ruby?

Answer (score 42):

I wrote a [much more detailed answer to this question](http://StackOverflow.Com/questions/884186/can-ruby-php-or-perl-create-a-pre-compiled-file-for-the-code-like-python/885171/#885171) in the question "[*Can Ruby, PHP, or Perl create a pre-compiled file for the code like Python?*](http://StackOverflow.Com/questions/884186/)"

The answer is: it depends. The Ruby *Language* has no provisions for compiling to bytecode and/or running bytecode. It also has no specfication of a bytecode format. The reason for this is simple: it would be much too restricting for language implementors if they were forced to use a specific bytecode format, or even bytecodes at all. For example, XRuby and JRuby compile to JVM bytecode, Ruby.NET and IronRuby compile to CIL bytecode, Cardinal compiles to PAST, SmallRuby compiles to Smalltalk/X bytecode, MagLev compiles to GemStone/S bytecode. For all of these implementations it would be plain stupid to use any other bytecode format than the one they currently use, since their whole point is interoperating with other language implementations that use the same bytecode format.

Simlar for MacRuby: it compiles to native code, not bytecode. Again, using bytecode would be stupid, since one of the goals is to run Ruby on the iPhone, which pretty much requires native code.

And of course there is MRI, which is a pure AST-walking script interpreter and thus doesn't have a bytecode format.

That being said, there *are* some Ruby *Implementations* which allow compiling to and loading from bytecode. Rubinius allows that, for example. (Indeed, it *has* to have that functionality since its Ruby compiler is written in Ruby, and thus the compiler must be compiled to Rubinius bytecode first, in order to solve the Catch-22.)

YARV also can save and load bytecode, although the loading functionality is currently disabled until a bytecode verifier is implemented that prevents users from loading manipulated bytecode that could crash or otherwise subvert the interpreter.

But, of course, both of these have their own bytecode formats and don't understand each other's (nor tinyrb's or RubyGoLightly's or ...) Also, neither of those formats is understood by a JVM or a CLR and vice versa.

However, the whole point is irrelevant because, as Mark points out, you can always reverse engineer the byte code anyway, especially in cases like CPython, PyPy, Rubinius, YARV, tinyrb, RubyGoLightly, where the bytecode format was specifically designed to be very close to the source language.

In general it is simply impossible to protect code that way. The reason is simple: you want the machine to be able to execute the code. (Otherwise what's the point in writing it in the first place?) However, in order to execute the code, the machine must *understand* the code. Since machines are much dumber than humans, it follows that any code that can be understood by a machine can just as well be understood by a human, no matter whether that code happens to be in source form, bytecode, assembly, native code or a deck of punch cards.

There is only one workable technical solution: if you control the *entire* execution pipeline, i.e. build your own CPU, your own computer, your own operating system, your own compiler, your own interpreter, and so forth and use strong cryptography to protect all of those, *then* and *only* then *might* you be able to protect your code. However, as e.g. Microsoft found out the hard way with the XBox 360, even doing all of that and hiring some of the smartest cryptographers and mathematicians on the planet, doesn't guarantee success.

The only *real* solution is not a technical but a social one: as soon as you have written your code, it is *automatically* fully protected by copyright law, without you having to do one single thing. That's it. Your code is protected.

Comment: Is there a performace impact/cost associated with no byte code generation ?

Comment: @Myth17: Theoretically yes, but in practice, it's almost completely negligible.

Comment: Running Ruby on the iPhone is not one of the goals of MacRuby - Hence the name **Mac** Ruby. For iOS development there is [RubyMotion](http://www.rubymotion.com/), which is developed by many of the same people.

Comment: @anthropomorphic: I'm referring to a comment made by Laurent Sansonetti sometime in 2008/2009, which went something like "I'm not allowed to say anything official but using this technology to run Ruby on a certain small handheld embedded device is definitely something I'm interested in." As you can see, I wrote that answer in 2009, if something has changed since then, feel free to edit it. Ironically, I haven't looked at MacRuby ever since I bought a Mac.

Comment: Ah. Well I just looked at the GitHub repository for RubyMotion, and it looks like the [initial commit](https://github.com/HipByte/RubyMotion/commit/c14c4326023f5bfec19439619cafff5db4d97b67) happened on June 1, 2012, so you couldn't have known about it at the time.

Answer (score 7):

The short answer is "YES",

check [rubini.us](http://rubini.us)

It will solve your problem.

Here is how to compile ruby code:

http://rubini.us/2011/03/17/running-ruby-with-no-ruby/

Answer (score 3):

Although Ruby's 1.9 YARV VM is a byte-code compiler I don't believe it can dump the byte-code to disk.  You might want to look at the alternative compiler, [Rubinius](http://rubini.us/), I believe it has this ability.  You should note though that byte-code pyc files (and I imagine the ruby equivalent) can be pretty easily "decompiled".

Answer (score 2):

Not with the MRI interpretter, no.

Some newer VM's are being worked on where this is on the table, but these aren't widely used (or even ready to be used) at this point.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Jruby, you can compile your Ruby code into Java .class files (including your Rails stuff) to execute them with (open)jdk out of the box!

You can even compile your complete stuff into a .war file to deploy it on Apache Tomcat or Jboss with a tool called "warbler"

https://rubygems.org/gems/warbler/

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your ruby.

1. JRuby - https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/JRubyCompiler
2. MRuby - http://mruby.org/docs/articles/executing-ruby-code-with-mruby.html
3. MRI (C)Ruby - https://devtechnica.com/ruby-language/compile-ruby-code-to-binary-and-execute-it