# Ruby equivalent of python's imp.load_compiled

Tags: python, ruby

I am looking for ruby implementation of compiled code loading in following python code:

```
global tuser, temail
tuser = **imp.load_compiled**('tuser', uplug)
temail = **imp.load_compiled**('temail', eplug)
```

Thanks.

Comment: CRuby doesn't have bytecode saving/loading (officially).

Comment: Ohh. I see. Any alternative?

Comment: You can use JRuby or Rubinius (or mruby). Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972388/is-it-possible-to-compile-ruby-to-byte-code-as-with-python.

Answer (score 0):

Use `RubyVM::InstructionSequence`: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/RubyVM/InstructionSequence.html

Example:
https://devtechnica.com/ruby-language/compile-ruby-code-to-binary-and-execute-it

```
# compiler.rb
source_code = File.open(ARGV[0], 'r')       # load the file from arguments
compiled_code = RubyVM::InstructionSequence.compile(source_code)
binary_code = compiled_code.to_binary
binary_file = File.open(ARGV[0].split('.').first + '.bin', 'w+')
binary_file.puts binary_code
binary_file.close

# exec.rb
executable_binary_code = File.open(ARGV[0], 'r').readlines.join('')
compiled_instruction_sequence = \
  RubyVM::InstructionSequence.load_from_binary(executable_binary_code)
compiled_instruction_sequence.eval
```

```sh
ruby compiler.rb fibonacci.rb
ruby exec.rb fibonacci.bin
```